# How to use rest_url_prefix filter in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, wp-api

How can I modify the WordPress REST API endpoint for my custom API endpoints only?

I'm using the WC API 2.6 also and I do not want to modify the endpoint for them. I just want to change the request endpoints for my custom API.

My API is built on `WC_REST_Controller` which further extends the `WP_REST_Controller` class.